# Order TableLayout column values programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a TableRow containing String data displayed as minutes.
I want to order/sort that column data programmatically.
Is that possible? I really need that feature.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you showed does not look like a single `TableRow`; in fact, it looks like 10.

Regardless, what you should do is keep a list of some kind with your data, and keep it sorted. An easy way to do this is keep a list of integers representing your minutes (in this case, 76, 84, 46, 68, 8, 9, 78, 78, 68, 46), then sort it. You can then re-fill your layout objects (whatever they are) with the sorted data.

```
ArrayList<Integer> minutes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
minutes.add(76);
minutes.add(84);
// ...
minutes.add(46);
Collections.sort(minutes);
```

Then, if you have your views already set up, you can reference each one using `findViewById()`, and call `setText()` on them to give them information, or create the views based on the data:

```
ViewGroup group = ...; // Might be a TableRow, LinearLayout, whatever...
group.removeAllViews();
for (Integer i : minutes) {
    // Create a new view
    yourView.setText(i + "'"); // Put it in 0' format
    group.addView(yourView);
}
```

Then, your `group` layout will contain a set of views representing your `minutes` array.

For what it's worth, it would be better to use a `ListView` here; this is what it was designed for.

Comment: Dude, you're the best. I mark "Accepted" because i knew what is your technic/method. Applying it right now. Thank you very much bro :).